# Loading some pages causes AH00124 redirect error

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, webserver

I started getting Error 500 when loading some pages on my Wordpress site and found out it's because of AH00124 redirect error.

```
[error] - www.johndoe.com - AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer https://www.johndoe.com/
```

This literally came out from nowhere since I didn't make significant changes to the site and the issue persists even after rolling back any possible changes.
Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?johndoe.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sito/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sito/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?johndoe.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sito/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here some pages that cause the error:
/blog
/wp-admin/edit.php (on post)
2019/03/26/any-article/

I think I can't log into the Apache server because we only pay for a web hosting, so I guess I can't have a look at backtraces.